# Passing a sub routine as parameter to another sub routine

Tags: c#, vb.net

i wrote a sub that creates excel file from access database table.
im passing to the sub some parameters so i can reuse it for any access table in my project.

i would like to add another parameter, but i cant figure out how to do it: i need that every excel file that i am creating will have different summery worksheet, so in order to do it i need to pass a different sub as parameter (like they have in Jquery). so my quastion is how can i pass to a sub routine to another sub routine as parameter? the ExportToExcelFromAccess() sub will execute the sub that was passed before saving the excel file.

Tagged also C#, I assume that passing methods in C# is quite similar to VB

```
Public Sub ExportToExcelFromAccess(ByVal accessFilePath As String, ByVal accesspassword As String, ByVal AccessFileTable As String, ByVal exWbNameForTempFolder As String, ByVal xlWsName As String, ByVal promtTheUserBeofore As Boolean, Optional ByVal columnsNames() As String = Nothing)

' doing stuff

end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do exactly what you asked for you could use a lambda expression:

```
Dim myAction As Action() = Sub() WriteYouLogicHereToCreateTheWorksheet()
```

which can be used in your Export method

```
Sub ExportToExcelFromAccess(ByVal accessFilePath As String, createAction As Action(), ...)
    createAction()
End Sub

ExportToExcelFromAccess(filePath, myAction)
```

The more idiomatic way of doing it would be to use polymorphism through inheritance/interfaces:

```
Public Interface IWorksheetCreator
    Sub CreateWorksheet()
End Interface

Public Class MyWorksheetCreator Implements IWorksheetCreator
    Sub CreateWorksheet() Implements IWorksheetCreator.CreateWorksheet
        WriteYouLogicHereToCreateTheWorksheet()
    End Sub
End Class

Sub ExportToExcelFromAccess(ByVal accessFilePath As String, _ 
   createAction As IWorksheetCreator)
    createAction.CreateWorksheet()
End Sub

'Create an instance of the class holding your desired logic
Dim myAction As New MyWorksheetCreator()
ExportToExcelFromAccess(filePath, myAction)
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly what i need. but what is the meaning of  idiomatic? (couldn't find it on google translate) do you mean more professional?

Comment: With ideomatic, I mean in line with how you usually solve a specific problem in a language/framework/context.

Answer (score -1):

Your ExportToExcelFromAccess could have a Func or Action parameter.

An alternative could be using delegates.

Comment: Aren't `Func` and `Action` delegates?

Comment: There are use cases where you must use delegates instead of Action or Funct. DllImport for example.